# Ubuntu-server install via chroot netplan wifi network unreachable

Tags: server, netplan

I just installed ubuntu 22.04 via chroot and also the ubuntu-server metapackage. I'm trying to connect via wifi only using netplan. I found some info about it but it doesn't work. I always get "network unreachable" error. After reboot the wifi is always down and when I set it up the light on adapter lights for a second and that's it.
Here is the netplan configuration file:
***01-network-manager-all***

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlx0374508a678:
      optional: true
      access-points:
       "the SSID"
         password: "the password"
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.11/24]
      getaway: [192.168.1.1]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8,192.168.1.1]
```

There isn't any other file in /etc/netplan folder.
When I use

> netplan generate --debug

I don't get any errors and the same with apply. I have installed wpasupplicant and the service is running

Comment: Try adding a colon after `"the SSID"` like so `"the SSID":`

Comment: Please see: `cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireless.yaml` Your yaml file varies somewhat and I suggest that you amend it to comply.

Comment: The colon didn't change anything. I'll see the examples file. Thanks.

Comment: I had a typo in yaml extension and that's why I didn't get any error. Using the wireless example I edit my file and eliminate the errors. After that when I ran "netplan apply" after a 1-2minutes delay I get an error: "a dependency job for netplan-wpa-wlan0.service failed and a traceback which I cannot write it(pc is not at the same room) with an exit status 1 at the end.

Comment: What does this tell us? `sudo dpkg -s wpasupplicant | grep Status`

Comment: Nevermind. It's working now. The problem was the name of usb wifi which include the NAT address and is a big name. So seems that from multiple edits and because I don't have an easy access to that pc I missed a character. After I tried to directly configure networkd and wpa_supplicant I managed to correct enable/start the services, which solve the delay issue, but I still couldn't connect. So I thought to give another try with netplan and I found that missed a character from wifi name.