# Wifi is repeatedly dropped and sometimes cannot reconnect without a PC restart

Tags: networking, wireless, netplan

I know this has been asked plenty of times already and a tonne of 'solutions' have been provided. Many of the solution did not work for me.
Edit: The solution did not work, so the problem persists.
<strike>I am posting this as I found something that *seems* to have worked and it may be useful for others.</strike>

I am not an IT/CompSci person so I please understand that I may not know all the technical ways to fix this.

My wifi has had the issue of 'dropping' shortly after connecting. The problem is consistent but sometimes it takes a few minutes before I lose the connection.
When I `ping ubuntu.com` I get  `ping: ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`
and if I `ping 8.8.8.8`  I get

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.178.105 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Occasionally the wifi will go switch between 'working' and not and I can't see why this should be the case (I am not doing anything different during these times).
During these times my ping looks like this :

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=116 time=872 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=116 time=76.7 ms
From 192.168.178.105 icmp_seq=38 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.178.105 icmp_seq=39 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.178.105 icmp_seq=40 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.178.105 icmp_seq=45 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=116 time=48245 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=116 time=47213 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=116 time=46189 ms
```

Most often the wifi just does not connect at all.

The wifi is not the 'obvious' problem as I have had this issue for more than three months on over 20 different wifis and hotspots. In all cases the wifi worked for my phone and other computers. Moreover, I can connect sometimes (seemingly randomly) but only for a few minutes.
The Ethernet works without a problem and the laptop can connect to the internet via a usb connection to my phone (which is accessing the wifi, not a data connection).

When the wifi is on, I cannot ping the computer from my phone (termux app) and I cannot ping the phone from the computer.

Results of...

```
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 3c:7c:3f:ea:00:4e
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-44-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:33 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fc904000-fc904fff memory:fc900000-fc903fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: 94:08:53:4c:47:d7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822ce driverversion=5.19.0-44-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.178.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:80 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fc800000-fc80ffff
```

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i firmware
[108304.658940] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to get tx report from firmware
[109316.179007] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to get tx report from firmware
```

```
ip a
```

When the wifi is working...

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:7c:3f:ea:00:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 94:08:53:4c:47:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.105/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 85601sec preferred_lft 85601sec
    inet6 fe80::1b92:c535:444d:c49b/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: mpqemubr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:66:d1:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.181.94.1/24 brd 10.181.94.255 scope global mpqemubr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe66:d1a5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:16:7e:75:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: lxdbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:cd:6f:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.8.182.1/24 scope global lxdbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd42:58a3:ec4:bc97::1/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fecd:6fd7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: vethfbd66b7f@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master lxdbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 16:bf:ba:4d:8c:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
11: veth68bc0cf0@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master lxdbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:8b:d1:15:4f:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
13: veth0f1e58de@if12: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master lxdbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether be:85:da:19:94:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 2
15: vethffbc257b@if14: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master lxdbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:97:21:29:d8:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 3
17: vetheb2a82f9@if16: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master lxdbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 16:26:66:99:c4:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 4
18: tap-f70da783792: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master mpqemubr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 86:06:5d:c4:9e:78 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::8406:5dff:fec4:9e78/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

When the wifi is NOT working...

````
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:7c:3f:ea:00:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 94:08:53:4c:47:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.105/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 85553sec preferred_lft 85553sec
    inet6 fe80::1b92:c535:444d:c49b/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: mpqemubr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:66:d1:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.181.94.1/24 brd 10.181.94.255 scope global mpqemubr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe66:d1a5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:16:7e:75:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: lxdbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:cd:6f:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.8.182.1/24 scope global lxdbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd42:58a3:ec4:bc97::1/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fecd:6fd7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: vethfbd66b7f@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master lxdbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 16:bf:ba:4d:8c:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
11: veth68bc0cf0@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master lxdbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:8b:d1:15:4f:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
13: veth0f1e58de@if12: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master lxdbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether be:85:da:19:94:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 2
15: vethffbc257b@if14: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master lxdbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:97:21:29:d8:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 3
17: vetheb2a82f9@if16: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master lxdbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 16:26:66:99:c4:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 4
18: tap-f70da783792: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master mpqemubr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 86:06:5d:c4:9e:78 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::8406:5dff:fec4:9e78/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever```
````

```
cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

```
cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireless.yaml 
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp2s0b1:
      regulatory-domain: "GB"
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.21/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8]
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "**********"
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.0.1
```

```
nmcli dev status
DEVICE             TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION          
wlp3s0             wifi      connected               TPLINK casadelsole2 
lxdbr0             bridge    connected (externally)  lxdbr0              
mpqemubr0          bridge    connected (externally)  mpqemubr0           
docker0            bridge    connected (externally)  docker0             
tap-f70da783792    tun       connected (externally)  tap-f70da783792     
54:71:DD:38:60:F6  bt        disconnected            --                  
enp2s0             ethernet  unavailable             --                  
veth0f1e58de       ethernet  unmanaged               --                  
veth68bc0cf0       ethernet  unmanaged               --                  
vetheb2a82f9       ethernet  unmanaged               --                  
vethfbd66b7f       ethernet  unmanaged               --                  
vethffbc257b       ethernet  unmanaged               --                  
lo                 loopback  unmanaged               --
```

System info:

```
OS: Ubuntu Sway 22.10 x86_64 
Host: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. FA506IH 
Kernel: 5.19.0-44-generic 
Uptime: 1 day, 6 hours, 31 mins 
Packages: 4319 (dpkg), 63 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.2.2 
WM: sway 
Terminal: kitty 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon Graphics (16) @ 2.900GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA NVIDIA Corporation TU117M 
GPU: AMD ATI Renoir 
Memory: 11834MiB / 39521MiB
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This 'solution' did not solve the problem.
In the end, I upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04 and with that the wifi problem went away.

I found this answer:
[Ubuntu-server install via chroot netplan wifi network unreachable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419459/ubuntu-server-install-via-chroot-netplan-wifi-network-unreachable)

This seems to have worked. It has only been a few hours right now but this is the longest the wifi has stayed connected in over three months so I am hoping this really was the solution.

I replaced the content of :

```
cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

using the content of the file below:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireless.yaml 
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp2s0b1:
      regulatory-domain: "GB"
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.21/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8]
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "**********"
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.0.1
```

I literally just copied it (even the asterisks).
but changing the `wlp2s0b1:` to the wifi on my laptop.
I then ran

```
sudo netplan apply
```

At first it seemed to have done nothing. After around 5 minutes the wifi reconnected and has not gone away yet.